# Selecting non-adjacent columns by column number pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have yet to find an answer for this anywhere. I am attempting to select columns number `2` and `86:100`. Obviously, I would rather not select them by label.

Intuitively I have tried: `df_new = df.iloc[:,[2,86:100]]` to no avail.

What is the most efficient way of selecting these columns?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to combine slices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3, 10)))

res = df.iloc[:, np.r_[2, 5:10]]

print(res)

          2         5         6         7         8         9
0  0.489923  0.406723  0.085721  0.235617  0.724768  0.398237
1  0.697457  0.565602  0.177975  0.215762  0.377650  0.658344
2  0.116625  0.770128  0.930788  0.367666  0.044933  0.486751
```