# How to select multiple columns by name that are not adjacent and combining several slicing methods?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Is there a way to select multiple columns that are not adjacent and combining several methods?

test dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 9),
                    columns=['ID', 'rfm_snittbeløp_gaver', 'rfm_maksbeløp_gaver', 'rfm_antall_kampanjer',
                             'a','b','c','d','e'])
```

Let's say I want the columns: **ID, all columns that start with rfm, a:c, and e**. In this order.

I thought something along these lines would do it, but I was not able to make it work

```
frames = [test.loc[:, 'ID'],
          test.loc[:, test.columns.str.startswith('rfm')],
          test.loc[:, 'a':'c'],
          test.iloc[:, -1]]

test_sub = pd.concat(frames)
```

I read it resets the index and that I won't be able to control the order of the columns.

Preferably there would be something like `np.r_` for `.loc` to combine slices as found in this post

1. [Selecting non-adjacent columns by column number pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052914/selecting-non-adjacent-columns-by-column-number-pandas)

But I do not like using index position when I refer to columns

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: by `a:c` do you mean `a,b,c` inclusive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a way using [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and [`get_loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and [`get_indexer()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
ID= test.columns.get_loc('ID')
rfm=test.columns.get_indexer(test.columns[test.columns.str.startswith('rfm')])
a=test.columns.get_loc('a')
c=test.columns.get_loc('c')
e=test.columns.get_loc('e')
```

---

```
test.iloc[:,np.r_[ID,rfm,a:c+1,e]]
```

---

```
         ID  rfm_snittbeløp_gaver  rfm_maksbeløp_gaver  rfm_antall_kampanjer  \
0  0.822275              0.155649             0.189058              0.050138   
1  0.188038              0.286731             0.509774              0.171374   
2  0.626211              0.477937             0.585987              0.358124   

          a         b         c         e  
0  0.652142  0.492184  0.464453  0.361395  
1  0.242480  0.963673  0.898177  0.813195  
2  0.863088  0.781858  0.924203  0.690219
```

Comment: This was quite neat, but what if I would have wanted columns from a:p, then I would need to create a lot of get_locs..

Comment: @Jon no, you would still need just 2 get loc. `a:c+1` gives you index of the range from a to c , for `a:p` replace `c` with `p` in the solution

Comment: ah, I see now. So with just a custom function on top of this to do the get_locs this is brilliant. Then I can just pass in the columns I want and slice and dice to my hearts content!

Comment: yep :) also this would solve your not liking to use index position when referring to column names. its a good feature to have for such purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty close, with `axis=1`:

```
frames = [test.loc[:, 'ID'],
          test.loc[:, test.columns.str.startswith('rfm')],
          test.loc[:, 'a':'c'],
          test.iloc[:, -1]]

test_sub = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach will be to create a class like the following:

```
class s_:
    """Create slices from given columns resembling numpy s_"""

    def __init__(self, cols):
        self.indices = pd.Series(cols, index=cols)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            result = []
            for indexing in item:
                try:
                    if isinstance(indexing, str): # treat strings as labels
                        result.append(self.indices[indexing])
                    else:
                        result.extend(self.indices[indexing])
                except TypeError:
                    result.append(self.indices[indexing])
            return result
        else:
            return self.indices[item]
```

You could do then:

```
columns = ['ID', 'rfm_snittbeløp_gaver', 'rfm_maksbeløp_gaver', 'rfm_antall_kampanjer', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 9), columns=columns)

print(test.loc[:, s_(test.columns)['ID', test.columns.str.startswith('rfm'), 'a':'c', -1]])
```

**Output**

```
         ID  rfm_snittbeløp_gaver  ...         c         e
0  0.026803              0.603409  ...  0.819486  0.396006
1  0.791049              0.450502  ...  0.097529  0.708746
2  0.623558              0.513678  ...  0.140740  0.958713

[3 rows x 8 columns]
```

Note that this also works for single indexing:

```
print(test.loc[:, s_(test.columns)['ID']])
```

**Output**

```
0    0.129801
1    0.786684
2    0.839015
Name: ID, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

One option for flexible column selection is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select_columns.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
test.select_columns('ID', 'rfm*', slice('a', 'c'), 'e')

         ID  rfm_snittbeløp_gaver  rfm_maksbeløp_gaver  rfm_antall_kampanjer         a         b         c         e
0  0.260244              0.890904             0.884521              0.600843  0.955812  0.213352  0.628574  0.428940
1  0.859678              0.330782             0.200329              0.774217  0.421452  0.494960  0.932772  0.454032
2  0.483668              0.894447             0.088583              0.806648  0.797400  0.240357  0.762199  0.069686
```

The `*` in`rfm*` ida is borrowed from unix.