# Selecting columns - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to select multiple columns in Python using `.iloc` function?

**Let's say I have data frame with X rows and 100 columns and I would like to select the first 50 columns then 75 to 80 and then columns 90 and 95.**

So far I read about two way of selection in Python, single columns `df = df1.iloc[:,[1,2,3]]` and range `df = df1.iloc[:,1:30]`, but is there any possibility how to combine then in more complex selection?

I.e. In my example I would expect code like this:

*But it does not work. I tried also different syntax (using brackets etc.) but cannot find the correct solution.*

```
df = df1.iloc[:,[1:50,75:80,90,95]]
```

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052914/selecting-non-adjacent-columns-by-column-number-pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should try using `np.r_`. In thid case, please try with:

```
df1.iloc[:, np.r_[1:50, 75:80, 90, 95]]
```

This should be able to allow you to select multiple groups of columns